Arithmetic versus floating-point operations, looking at Agner Fog's Tables: are really floating-point operations more expensive?
I have always though that floating-point operations are much more expensive than integers operations, but looking at Agner Fog's tables, for example, IceLake:

I see that integer division costs (latency) from 12 to 19 cycles, while floating-point division from 14-16.
Integer multiplication costs from 3 to 4 cycles, while floating-point multiplication exactly 4 cycles.
The reciprocal thoughtputs doesn't seem too different either.
Addition/substraction is indeed like 3x more expensive for floating-point operations (as latency).

So, when we say that "floating-point operations are more expensive", which kind of operations are people thinking of? Because the sentence "is more expensive" is implicitely associated with multiplication/division, but I haven't seen the actual difference, at least according to those tables.

FP being expensive, just like float has no benefit over double falls comfortably into the realm of lies to little children that stopped being true roughly when we stopped using x87 instructions. Of course latency can be a significant issue, especially when the instructions form a loop-carried dependency chain. And small integer types like short and signed char allow higher throughput through vectorization.
